# Confused on SQL Relationships

Tags: sql, relational-database

I am confused in SQL Relationships, specially with One to One and One to Many. I have read many articles like [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561) and [this](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1to1/)

For an example, below are some statements from those articles and some other articles

1. The relationship between customer and address tables are one to one, that is because one address is belong to one customer.
2. The relationship between customer and order tables are one to many, that is because one customer can make many orders.
3. customer and contactData tables are one to one because one contactData is belong to one customer

Yes, true, but take my argument now.

- In point 2 it says the relationship is one to many, but one order is belong to exact one customer right? So you can consider it as one to one as well.
- In point 3, contactData and customer relationship said to be one to one, but one customer can have many contactData right? So it is one to many

With all of these, I am seriously confused. Can someone give me a clear definition about how to find the relationship please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The relationship between customer and order tables are one to many, that is because one customer can make many orders.

This should better read

- a customer can place **many** orders
- an order belongs to **one** customer

So it is a **one to many** relationship between the tables.

> customer and contactData tables are one to one because one contactData is belong to one customer

This should better read

- a contactData belongs to **one** customer
- a customer can only have **one** contactData

So it is a **one to one** relationship between the tables.

Yes, in reality a customer of some company may have more than one contact, but in this particular database they are talking about, it is defined that a customer can have only one contactData.

EDIT: I should add that you can say "there is a one to many relationship between tables a and b", which doesn't specify which is which, so you can be more precise, saying "there is a one to many relationship from table a to b" or "there is a many to one relationship from table b to a". With one to one, you don't have such problem of course. (Adding to this, there are even more precise definitions, such as a "one to one or zero" etc. where you specify if zero records are allowed, such as a person without contact data.)

Comment: OK, what about something like this.. Imagine we are recording the `Pension_History` of an employee. Every year he get his Pension, so in the table after few years there should be many pensions belong to one `employee`. This relationship as I see is `one to many`, am I correct?

Comment: Yes. Every pension belongs to **one** person; every person can have **many** pensions.

Answer (score 2):

Dongle. You are making a mistake of looking at the subject symmetrically. Relationship is considered to be one-directional, that's why you felt confused.

Let's take for example this *Customer <-> Order* relation. Like you observed, *customer -> order* is something completely different than *order -> customer*. They are actually independent, however weird it may be. It's because in the real code you're never actually dealing with two objects at once, rather than "acting" from perspective one of the two. E.g. you fetched order object from the db and only then you're who is the customer that made this order. Or you have the customer object and you want to check what are his orders.

As you see, this is very uni-directional (we call relations uni- or bi-directional). You have object X and you want to "enhance" your knowledge of it, by joining it with the other table, object Y. So it's *X->Y*. Or *Y->X*. But never actually it is *X<->Y*. That's why **you always have to look at the relations as if they were independent**.

Apart from that, you're right and it usually is so, that one relation is *One to One* and the other *One to Many*.

Comment: Hi, Please explain more.

Comment: Hi. Edited my answer a bit. Hope it will get clearer. But it's not that big deal actually. Once you write some queries, it will be just an abstract detail. You will feel it as you use it! :- )

Comment: Your answer conflicts with JusticeJuice's answer above!

Answer (score 2):

Point 2 is clearly `one to many` because one `customer` can have multiple `orders` but every `order` belongs to exactly one `customer`.

You have to read the relations in both directions.

Imagine this relation was `one to one`. You would need to create a new customer account every time you want to place a new order.

Point 3 is probably a design question. If you want to allow multiple `contactData` there is no reason to keep it `one to one`.

Comment: Your answer conflicts with `Rav`'s answer below!

Comment: @Dongle at which part? I don't see a conflict.

Comment: @Dongle He just split the relation in two relations. I said read the relation in both directions. Which is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your "point 2" got answered by Rav.

"point 3": I found in one of your first links the one to one example with "Addresses" table. In this example a customer can have one address only. So if your customers can have more then one you will need one to many (as in the example Orders).

Comment: More than one address means more than one address "rows" right? We can also save many addresses in the same row, belong to many columns, like address1, address2, address3 etc.

Comment: Yes, you are connecting "Address" table rows with "Customer" table rows via the foreign key. In one to one you can connect only one customer row with one address row. And yes, you can save more addresses with more columns in the same row but that is not a relationship and you will be limited by the number of columns you have assigned for addresses. I wouldn't recommend it. It's better to have a one to many relationship.